# DateTimePicker and seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I've searched SO, but could't get the answer. I use a DateTimePicker on a WinForms dialog and specify a custom format: `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`. But DateTimePicker doesn't show the seconds, it always shows `00` for them. Even if I type e.g. "15" seconds, the value is correct but it's shown wrong.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you set the `Format` to `custom` ? because I tried it and it shows the current time seconds

Comment: @Nacereddine: Yes, I did and I can see the date formated in the way I expect it.

Comment: [Works for me too](http://i.imgur.com/nmi5B.png). You must have something else going wrong.

Comment: @Fischermaen It's [working fine](http://i.imgur.com/GndoN.png) for me at design time and runtime. Do you have some other parts of your code that modify that DateTimePicker ? Did you try it at runtime ?

Comment: DTP is implemented by Windows, not .NET.  DateTimePicker is just a wrapper class for it.  Unanswerable without knowing what Windows version you use.  You'd better also look at Control Panel + Regional and Language options for user overrides.

Comment: Test is running under Windows 7 SP 1. All language settings are for Germany. But I don't think that not displaying the seconds has anything to do with the language settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the answer by myself. If I bind the data source to the Text property of DateTimePicker, the seconds will not be shown. I have to bind to the Value property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Format property before specifying your custom format?

```
public void SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
}
```

[Example cadged from the MSDN page for DateTimePicker.CustomFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Comment: I specified those values in the property sheet of the designer.