# Edit datetime in c#

Tags: c#

I have a dateTimePicker1 in my form and it  display the time with hour and seconds but i just need to display just the day like 27/11/2014 00:00:00
And this is my code

```
DateTime dt1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1);
```

Comment: Here is what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only

Comment: Did you try to use search first?

Comment: `DateTimePicker.Value` is already a `DateTime` why you need to convert it ? Its not clear what you exactly need? do you need the Date portion or you only want to show Date with no time in your control.

Comment: If you're only needing to display the day, why are you including an empty timestamp? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime d1 = dt1.Date;
```

gives you only the date potion

Answer (score 2):

```
 d1.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

go to your `dateTimePicker1`'s properties and select `Custom` for `Format` option. than go to `Custom Format` option and `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. You can make your own format from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if u look at form before ask u could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359380/datetimepicker-and-seconds) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93472/datetimepicker-pick-both-date-and-time)